# Maven release-plugin doesn't update LATEST version

Tags: maven, deployment, nexus, maven-release-plugin

I am releasing my project using Maven release-plugin and strange thing happens. Release version is updated in

```
maven-metadata.xml
```

but not the LATEST version:

```
<metadata>
  <groupId>***</groupId>
  <artifactId>***</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <latest>1.0.0.2</latest>
    <release>1.0.0.4</release>
    <versions>
      <version>1.0.0.0</version>
      <version>1.0.0.1</version>
      <version>1.0.0.2</version>
      <version>1.0.0.4</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20140529090759</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

As a result, I am able to download artifact by specifying version explicitly, but trying to get latest version results in older script being downloaded.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by `get latest version` can you show your pom file? Which Maven Version do you use?

Comment: I mean using Nexus syntax: ...&v=LATEST...

Comment: Have you tried to regenerate the meta data via UI of Nexus? BTW: Which Maven version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

The "latest" tag is only set for Maven plugin artifacts.  See here for an explanation:

https://support.sonatype.com/entries/23778606

If you're trying to get the highest version from a Maven build you should use a version range.